# iOS: controlling size of assets designed in Cinema 4D when importing into Xcode?

Tags: ios, assets, xcode, collada, cinema-4d

A designer provided the [attached two DAE files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h6itbar1leetmko/AAApCMdnkUJj4YTvyFST3MuQa?dl=0) created in [Cinema 4D](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/infosites/product-comparison/). The characters in these DAE files are to be integrated into an `iOS` game.

Both assets are of comparable size inside of `Cinema 4D`. Both DAE files were produced with the same export process.

Importing the DAE files into a SceneKit scene, however, produces different results.

`Chango.dae` imports at a "normal" size with a bounding box of `~3x4x3`.

`Tiki.dae` imports at a huge size with a bounding box of `~155x325x140`. Its dimensions inside Cinema 4D is `122x283x142`.

Questions:

1) How do you make sure assets "fit" into a `SceneKit` scene? Are you supposed to scale down assets with the "scale" property of the `SCNNode`, or are you supposed to ask the designer to make the asset of a certain size? In `SpriteKit` and `UIKit`, this is straightforward. The asset size correlates directly to its screen size (e.g., `20x20` icon takes about that much screen space depending on resolution). However, what's the analog for `SceneKit`? If you want an asset to fit into a `1x1x1` `SCNNode`, what size do you ask the designer to make the asset?

2) If your asset is too large for a scene, how do you scale it down? In `UIKit`, for instance, you can scale an image to fit a `UIView` with something like `ScaleAspectFit`. There doesn't seem to be an analog for a `SCNNode`. Using the `SCNNode`'s `scale` property changes the appearance, but doesn't change the asset's bounding box. And even changing the appearance isn't precise. For instance, with `Tiki.dae`, the original height of the asset (as shown by the bounding box) is 324.36. If you set the Y-scale to 0.01, however, the height doesn't become ~3.24. It becomes smaller than 3, which you can prove by fitting it comfortably within a sphere of height 3 (radius of 1.5).

Answer (score 1):

You can always click on your `.dae` in the `Scene Graph View`, then adjust the scale in the Node Inspector. I'm using the same workflow from `C4D` to `Xcode` and I have to shrink things down to something absurdly small like `x: 0.0001 y: 0.0001 z: 0.0001` so there must be something I'm missing too.

Comment: Doesn't the exporter have a scaling feature?